# Why is 'this' undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, blur

I have an input called #question_title. I want to run an if statement on a Blur event. When I try to check the length it comes back as undefined. Any ideas why 'this' isn't working here?

**JS**

```
$('#question_title').on('blur', function(){
    console.log('this.length = ' + this.length);
    if ( this.length > 1 ) {
        // do something fabulous
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group question-title-wrap">
    <label for="question_title">What is your question?</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="question_title">
</div>
```

Comment: In that "blur" handler, `this` will refer to the DOM node for the `<input>` element, not the value. Try `this.value.length`.

Comment: `$(this).val().length` is the jQuery way to do this.

Comment: Thats it :) Please add as an answer. Tx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` refers to the element itself, not its value, hence the error `undefined` as there is no such property (`length`) on the input element.

If you use `this.value.length` you'll get the value and its length though.

```js
$('#question_title').on('blur', function(){
    console.log('this.value.length = ' + this.value.length);
    if ( this.value.length > 1 ) {
        // do something fabulous
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group question-title-wrap">
    <label for="question_title">What is your question?</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="question_title">
</div>
```